# how to transform data frame in r

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame

```
newDF<-data.frame(type=c(rep("A",4),
                  rep("B",2),rep("C",3),
                  rep("D",4),rep("E",4)), 
                  cluster=sample(1:4,17,replace=T), 
                  count=sample(1:20, 17, rep=T), 
                  sum=sample(30:1000,17,rep=T))
```

And I need to get 2 new data frames, which would have "cluster" as columns, type as rows and count as fill.(second table will be the same, but fill=sum, not count). There must be some NA's in these 2 tables, because newDF has 17 rows, but two new data frames must be 5x5

How can I create these 2 5x5 data frames?

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: I don't think that works as there are duplicate identifier  You may need `library(reshape2);dcast(newDF, type~cluster, value.var='sum', sum)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I have already found answer

```
spread(newDF[,-3],key=cluster, value=sum)
```

Comment: Based on the data you showed, I get `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (8, 9), (12, 13), (1, 2, 3, 4), (16, 17)`.  May be `library(dplyr);newDF %>% group_by(cluster) %>% mutate(Seq=row_number()) %>% select(-count) %>% spread(key=cluster, value=sum)`

Comment: sure, i work with another data, newDF is just test data frame. For newDF i need to delete duplicated rows or to summarise them using group_by

Comment: When you post examples, that need to mimic the original data.  Solutions differ based on the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(reshape2)
countoutput <- dcast(newDF,type~cluster,value.var = "count",fun.aggregate = sum)
sumoutput <- dcast(newDF,type~cluster,value.var = "sum",fun.aggregate = sum)
```

It fills missing values with 0, but you could specify a different number (e.g. -1) by adding the argument `fill = -1` to help highlight which are missing values... I can't seem to get it to put NA instead of 0, but I haven't tried for very long.